# "git clone http://junk abc" removes abc

Tags: git, clone

abc is previously created empty directory. If you are trying to clone from http/ssh connection and there is a problem with that connection directory is removed. Is there any way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Can confirm the same behaviour for me with `2.7.4` - I'd say this feels like a bug and you should probably report it: https://git-scm.com/community

Comment: It's sort of a mild bug. The target directory is the one that would hold the clone. The cloning process starts and gets partway through, filling the directory with stuff; then something fails, so Git cleans up, by removing the stuff. Along with the stuff, it removes the directory itself, as if it had made the directory. But since the directory was empty, the only thing you really lost is the owner and mode-bits of the directory inode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is intentional, but to prevent it, you can change into that directory, and then clone into the current directory:

```
cd abc && git clone http://junk .
```

or

```
git -C abc clone http://junk .
```

Now, although Git will still attempt to remove the directory, the removal will fail.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.